# Sennheiser pc 333d can only set to stereo

Tags: windows-7, headset, surround-sound

I just bought a Sennheiser pc 333d headset, installed the driver and everything, but at the last step I have to go into my sound settings and set the headset to 7.1. however I only have the option for stereo.

Any idea why I can't choose 7.1?

I'm running Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was the driver that came with the headset.
I fixed it simply by uninstalling it and downloading the driver from their website instead

http://en-de.sennheiser.com/gaming-headset-stereo-dolby-headphone-pc-333d

Comment: That page now provies only Win 10 drivers. Do you perhaps have Win 7 drivers downloaded to share with me?

Comment: Here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3BLwu7Vb2U-NWZQNEpvM25SX0U/view?usp=sharing